# Can't add New Relic through Windows Azure Add On Store

Tags: azure

When adding New Relic through the Windows Azure Add On Store I always get the following message on step 2 which prevents me from adding it:

We cannot provide a billing estimate at this time. Please try again later. If this error persists, contact support with the following information.

(The market on the billing account does not match the market on the user account (DM - ActivityId = xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx))

I would like some help to understand:
1) Why this might be happening?

2) Whether I need to add it in this way or can I simply sign up directly to New Relic, add the component to my Azure Website/Cloud Service via Nuget and configure it with my New Relic key?

Comment: You may add your credit card details for issue 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with option 2 and bypass the marketplace. New Relic integration with the Azure Marketplace is not very good — it is difficult to modify the subscription or administer accounts. One of the biggest problems is that the support link doesn't work, which means that you can wait days for a response because they cannot associate a support ticket with a paying customer.

Signing up directly with New Relic, and not through the store, is technically simple — all you need is the New Relic key.

The pricing from the Azure store is cheaper than that published on the New Relic site. I explained to them the problems with their Azure marketplace integration and they were gracious enough to match the Azure marketplace pricing.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Simon - I will try this, could you tell me whether I should install 'NewRelic.Agent.Api.x64' or 'New Relic x64 for Windows Azure' into my WebSite from Nuget?

Comment: Sorry, ignore last comment. It was the NewRelic.Azure.WebSite package from Nuget I needed and also needed to setup some App Settings in Azure as per this doc page: https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/azure-web-sites#key_values